# BlueCove library bluecove not available - Error using Bluecove/Java

Tags: bluetooth, java, jsr82, bluecove

How do I install Bluecove in Ubuntu 11/Eclipse IDE?

As far as i was aware, all I had to do was add the bluecove.jar and bluecove-gpl.jar to the Build-Path of the project within Eclipse.

I'm using some sample Bluecove code found here: http://bluecove.sourceforge.net/bluecove/apidocs/overview-summary.html#DeviceDiscovery

When I compile it, I'm getting an error: Native Library bluecove_x64 not available
Exception in thread "main" javax.bluetooth.BluetoothStateException: BlueCove library bluecove not available

Obviously, my Bluetooth USB dongle is plugged in when I do this...
I definitely have BlueZ protocol stack installed.

What am I doing wrong? Is Bluecove supported by 64-bit Linux? I've also been trying to get it installed on a CentOS 5.5 machine as well, but with no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank-you

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found an solutution to the problem.

for ubuntu version

```
sudo apt-get install libbluetooth-dev
```

for fedora version

```
yum install bluez-libs-devel
```

should do the trick

Source: http://bluecove.org/bluecove-gpl/

Source: http://yasir03.online.fr/?p=267

The package has a differant name in CentOS 5.5... it is

```
bluez-libs-devel-3.7-1.1.x86_64  <---64-bit
bluez-libs-devel-3.7-1.1.i386  <---32-bit
```

Comment: @Ryan Jones
[http://yasir03.online.fr/?p=267](http://yasir03.online.fr/?p=267) gives 403 error.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I am still getting `Native Library bluecove_x64 not available
Exception in thread "main" javax.bluetooth.BluetoothStateException: BlueCove library bluecove not available;
resource not found libbluecove_x64.so
load [bluecove_x64] no bluecove_x64 in java.library.path`